# Hardware issues with 2 series condensers with heat pump in heat mode

Tags: energy-storage

[This question previously asked on the DIY section of StackExchange, incorrectly, re-asking here]

I am planning to use a second heat exchanger to added inline to remove heat from a standard mini split heat pump system. The refrigerant will flow from the compressor to an added water coil exchanger, then on to the expected wall unit.

I am interested in constructive reasons why this could cause premature hardware failure, or otherwise wouldn't work. Specifically, if all the refrigerant was condensed in the first exchanger and only a liquid flowed to the second air exchanger in the wall unit.

Some background:
This type of configuration is already used, it's called a desuperheater.

[Desuperheater from Nordic](https://www.nordicghp.com/product/nordic-products/external-desuperheater/)

It is often used to produce domestic hot water, as it can be as hot as the superheated refrigerant leaving the compressor. What I think is unique about my situation is that I would like to pull a majority of the heat out, so much that there may be only small amounts of gas refrigerant left, or maybe none (all converted to liquid by releasing heat).

I wonder if there is any issue with colder than expected refrigerant returning to the compressor.

My goal is to store energy via warming water (when there is excess capacity in the system = warm outside in the day), for use in radiant heat during times when the heat pump is less efficient (night time cold outside).

My plan includes some automation that will adjust the flow of water through the exchanger, as well as manipulate the temperature setpoint of the indoor air handler to achieve the desired total heat flow (aka mass flow, compressor speed).

For example, if only 30% of a systems capacity is being used, increase the output to 80% and extract 50% via water temperature increase for use later.

The documentation for the mini split lists that it will diagnose an error (no refrigerant) if it sees no refrigerant temperature drop across the air handlers exchanger for a sustained period of time. It is my assessment that as long as there is some temperature drop it cannot know the other exchanger is using the majority of the heat.

In the image below, the first heat exchanger is in orange, and the air handling unit is in pink(ish).

[image: Log log plot of Enthalpy and Pressure with isotherm lines for the refrigeration cycle. First exchanger is orange highlight, second is pink.]

Comment: Perhaps this is the incorrect location again. How would I migrate this to the physics area of stack exchange?

Comment: I think Engineering would be a better place.

Comment: "Flag".... "moderator attention"... "move to <destination stack here>"

Comment: The entrance condition has to be 100% vapor. The orange has to operate entirely on vapor superheat and must not cause any condensation. You could try running the units in parallel, But the system efficiencies would probably be less than if you just used a gas hot water heater for the hot water. As a DIY project, I expect you would destroy the machine in short order.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Phil! Do you why it would cause damage? I've had someone else tell me that it would simply result in less heat output from the indoor air condenser... Not being a pain, just looking for more specifically what would break. I've tried to ask the manufacturer, but I would need to be a licensed HVAC person before they would reply...